# How to search a string in the another string in c++?

Tags: c++, string, search, char

```
int main(){
string s1="gandalf";
string s2="dal";
function(s1,s2);
return 0;

}
```

in the function, if there is "dal" in the string s1, return 1.
else return 0

Comment: What prevented you from simply reading the `std::string` documentation?

Answer (score 6):

Try the following

```
bool function( const std::string &s1, const std::string &s2 )
{
    return s1.find( s2 ) != std::string::npos;
}
```

If you want to write the function yourself using loops then it can look the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

bool function( const std::string &s1, const std::string &s2 )
{
    bool found = false;

    if ( !( s1.size() < s2.size() ) && !s2.empty() )
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0; !found && i < s1.size() - s2.size() + 1; i++ )
        {
            size_t j = 0;
            while ( j < s2.size() && s1[i+j] == s2[j] ) ++j;
            found = j == s2.size();
        }
    }

    return found;
}

int main() 
{
    std::string s1 = "gandalf";
    std::string s2 = "dal";

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << function( s1, s2 ) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
true
```

Comment: Posting answers directly will make things very easy for guys. You should help them by pointing them in the right direction rather than spoon feeding them.

Comment: @Pratik  I think that asnwers should make things very easy.:)

Comment: it does, but shouldn't it be about working towards achieving your answer, rather than just copy paste and use them. It will impact the learning curve.

Comment: @Pratik I am not a professor that to give new assignments.:)

Answer (score 0):

```
void fonk(string a, string b){
char x[10],y[10];
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
x[i]=a[i];
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
y[i]=b[i];

for(int j=0;j<10;j++){
    if(x[j]==y[0]&&x[j+1]==y[1]&&x[j+2]==y[2])
    cout<<"true"<<endl;
    else
    cout<<"false"<<endl;
```

}
}

Comment: The code is bad because you are using magic number 10 and strings' sizes can be either less or greater than 10

Comment: Next time, it's probably better to post your attempt directly in your question. In that way people can see that you indeed tried to solve the problem, and prod you in the right direction.